Do I pay zakah even if im not working
Asalamwalaykum,
I am a 18 year old student and am studying to get into university, I have money laying around from saving for years.
My question is do i pay zakah as i dont work and ill just be losing all this money over the years, is  there a hadith or surah that advises me on my current situation
Jazakalah

Zakat has nothing to do with income, as long as you have savings you need to pay zakat. You could however invest the money.
